# Does an ajax call on a web page affect page load time?

Tags: angular, performance, web

I've a single page application and after all the assets are loaded , I'm making multiple ajax call inside my angular application page. The question is will the api time add into page load time. On the chrome browser , it's showing weird behaviour, sometimes ajax time adds into page load time and sometime it doesn't. How the new relic records duration which is equivalent to page load time in chrome browser. Does it count api time as well for duration?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to better understand how New Relic determines Pageview duration.

[Pageview duration](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/data-apis/understand-data/event-data/events-reported-browser-monitoring/) measures load time of the page in the end user’s browser. You can see in that doc that [Ajax requests](https://docs.newrelic.com/attribute-dictionary/?attribute_name=&events_tids%5B%5D=8302&event=AjaxRequest) should be included in that calculation.

If you are finding that they are inconsistently accounted for and need help figuring it out, please feel free to reach out to the New Relic support team in our [support community](https://discuss.newrelic.com/).